# TMC5160 the outputs signals do not work correctly

Tags: mosfet, spi, output, motordriver, schematic

I have a Problem with TMC5160.
I use the spi communication and I have measured the signal, they are correctly.
But on Output of TMC5160 I have a problem. My MOS-FETS do not work correct. I measure on all coils pins 30V.
This is the schematic

[image]

On the schematic I did not tie the CLK on Ground but I did it later on print.
VCC_IO is also with 5V connected.
I just ask myself, whether the schematic would be correct so?

Comment: "I measure[...]" with what? A multimeter or an oscilloscope?

Comment: Also, what FETs are you using?

Comment: This is the MOS-FET that I used "NTDS015N15MC".
I have measured it with oscilloscope.
I have my circuit also connected with a silent step stick then it has worked. But without the silent step-stick, doesnt work correctly. That is why I assume that problem is anywhere on driver side but I don`t know where.

Comment: What's a "silent step-stick"?

Comment: It is a driver board from trinamic. With TMC5160 und the MOS-FETs Bridge. It is used to make it easier to control a step-motor.